# Red Underline script JSON

Tags: json, laravel

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
    const csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    const APP_URL = {!!json_encode(url('/')) !!}

    $("#chTahun").on('change', function() {
        const th = $(this).val()
        getChart(th)
    })

    getChart()
    ...
    ...
</script>
@endpush
```

const APP_URL = {!!json_encode(url('/')) !!}

when I Format Selection, this code always error, this is thing annoying

Comment: Why json encode ? it's a string, simply `const APP_URL = "{{ url('/') }}"`

Comment: Depending on the IDE you are using you might have the option to get a plugin for blade support. I know that both PHPStorm and VSCode have such plugins

Comment: what should I do to solve that error underline?